# WP Enqueuing Issues: Script not loading files

Tags: css, wordpress

Good day, I'm fairly new to Wordpress. I'm enqueuing all my css and js files on wordpress and followed the tutorial (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) and it doesn't seem to be linking my css/js I know for a fact since my site runs on Bootstrap and the grids aren't visible.

Here's my script:

```
function add_theme_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

wp_enqueue_style( 'mcm-bw', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/mcm-bw.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');

wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');

wp_enqueue_style( 'headers.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/headers.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');

wp_enqueue_style( 'espresso', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/espresso.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');

wp_enqueue_style( 'google-search', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/google-search.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');

wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);

 wp_enqueue_script( 'cse', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cse.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);

wp_enqueue_script( 'headersfooters', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/headersfooters.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);


if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

Update:
Here's a screenshot of my page source
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIh5O.png)

Comment: what if you see the code source? is there any style/script ?

Comment: also, do you use child theme? and where you placed the code provided?

Comment: I'm working off a blank HTML5 template and when I view my page source, it seems to be linking it. See photo above.

Comment: all files are there. what's the problem?

Comment: The files are there but are not being read. It could be a server/directory issue. I ended up just linking the files from the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to use this way? getting from web, also if you post the website link we can check this out e try to help,

```
    wp_enqueue_style( 'boostrap', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' , array(), '', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js', array() ,null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popper','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js', array() ,null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap','https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery') ,null, true );
```

and did you call in the

header.php

```
 <?php wp_head();?>
```

footer.php

```
 <?php wp_footer();?>
```

I usually do It

```
function carrega_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'boostrap', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' , array(), '', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array() ,null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js', array() ,null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popper','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js', array() ,null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap','https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery') ,null, true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'carrega_scripts');
```

here I have my style.css to customize all my layout and a main.js to create my scripts

Comment: Yes the header and footers are working fine. I'll try pulling web files.  I'm working of a personal server with WP installed.

Comment: It seems to be pulling the web links! Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome, I would recommend you create a assets folder and use that to separate css and js, like I do, I will update my answer with I usually do.